# How to set daterangepicker to ONLY YEARS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I've been using AdminLTE bootstrap for my UI. It already comes with datepicker and daterangepicker plugins. I've been looking for answers on how to set the datarangepicker to show only years but so far I've only come across setting datepicker to the format I want. I tried using the solution for datepicker on setting my daterangepicker to only years but it didn't workout for me. How can I do this? I don't want to use datepicker because it only selects a single date compared to daterangepicker which allows me to select 2 dates in one go.

Here's the datepicker solution I tried. It only works for datepicker but not in daterangepicker:

```
$('#reservation').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: "years"});
```

I tried including this in my daterangepicker but nothing happened:

```
$('#reservation').daterangepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: "years"});
```

Here's what my daterangepicker looks like currently:

[image]

Here's how I want my daterrangepicker to somewhat look like (taken from datepicker):

[image]

Comment: do you want from year and to year

Comment: "*I tried using the solution for datepicker on setting my daterangepicker to only years but it didn't [work] for me.*" - and what solution is that? Please show the code that didn't work, that way we can *see* what you've tried and, perhaps, spot other errors in your code that might be the cause of it 'not working.' Incidentally, what did you expect that code to do, and what did it do wrong? We can guess what you mean, from the question, but it's much better to be clear and specific about expectations and results.

Comment: Hi sorry about that. I edited my question including the solution. I tried to include the link at first but stackoverflow does not give me the privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best way I found -> [link](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range)

Use bootstrap-datepicker whis this code:

```js
$('#education-range input').each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: " yyyy",
            viewMode: "years",
            minViewMode: "years"
        });
        $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group input-daterange" id="education-range">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05">
                                <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19">
</div>
```