# Using Shiny dateRangeInput to select only years

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to implement something like the following post:

[How to set daterangepicker to ONLY YEARS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058714/how-to-set-daterangepicker-to-only-years)

I would like my `dataRangeInput()` to only accept values of years.

Currently the `dataRangeInput()` displays years but then goes on to ask for the month and day. I would like to avoid this since I am using yearly data and not daily/monthly.

Code:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  dateRangeInput(
    inputId = "myInputID",
    label = h4("Year"),
    start = as.Date("1990-01-04"),
    end = as.Date("2005-10-23"),
    # min = as.Date("1990-01-04"),
    # max = as.Date("2022-10-23"),
    startview = "year",
    language = "es",
    format = "yyyy",
    separator = " - "
    #startview = "decade"
  ),

  actionButton(inputId = "apply_analysis", label = "Aplicar", icon = icon("play")),

  plotOutput("out")


)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  out = eventReactive(input$apply_analysis, {
    managers %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column("Date") %>%
    mutate(year = lubridate::year(Date)) %>%
      filter(year > input$myInputID)
  })


  output$myPlot = renderPlot({
    out() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = year, y = HAM1)) +
      geom_line() +
      theme_bw()
})
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `dateInput` and `dateRangeInput` are dedicated to require an input *date* (regardless of how the input value is formatted for browser display). You could try a combination of two `numericInput`s, or `numericRangeInput` of package shinyWidgets and convert the integers to a date class.

Comment: I think the `shinyWidgets` [package](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/airDatepicker.html) with `airDatepicker` should be able to select year ranges.

Comment: As @Godrim points out, using `shinyWidgets` you can view the demo app `demoAirDatepicker("years")`; it surely has what you want